# How do I find the volume xyz tends to 0 when x(or y or z) tends to go $ \infty $

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

The volume V=xyz, and the constraint of surface area : S(x,y,z) = xy + yz + zx - 5 = 0, How do I comfirm the limit of volume V tends to 0 when x tends to go to $ \infty $?  $$ \bbox[yellow]
{\lim_{x\to\infty} \ V = 0 \ }$$
I found this problem in the vector calculus(Marsden), but there is no exact anwser for it. How exactly could I show V goes to 0 when x goes to infinity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible simple way is to extract $z$ from the constraint
$$z=\frac{5-x y}{x+y} \implies V=\frac{x y (5-x y)}{x+y}$$
$$\frac{\partial V}{\partial x}=-\frac{y^2 \left(x^2+2 x y-5\right)}{(x+y)^2}\tag 1$$
$$\frac{\partial V}{\partial y}=-\frac{x^2 \left(2 x y+y^2-5\right)}{(x+y)^2}\tag 2$$
SInce the partial derivatives are supposed to be $0$, from $(1)$
$$y=\frac{5-x^2}{2 x}\implies V=-\frac{1}{2} x \left(x^2-5\right)$$ So $V$ cancels when $x=\sqrt 5$ so, it is $0$ above.

Comment: This is great! Thank you. By the way there is one thing I coud not understand. Would you teach me why the partial derivatives are supposed to be 0?

Comment: @seonlee. Just because you are looking for an extremum. Take the case of $y=x^2-3x+5$; its minimum is attained when $2x-3=0$. Same problem in multiple dimensions. Is this OK for you ? Cheers :-)